# Matlab, Simulink, Making connection between multiple simulink models via Lan

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink, synchronization, xpc-target

There is a Simulink model composed of some subsystems, It is supposed to run each subsystem in a computer and all computers are connected to a LAN network.

There are interconnections between these subsystems and data shall be transferred between them so they should run synchronously and preferably real time.

But the computers have Windows operating system and so they do not have real time operating system.

I am searching to find a solution for this problem. what I have found up to now is that:

1. Simulink real time workshop can make executable code of simulink models but the code can be run real time just with real time processors and it doesn't seem that they can support connection between multiple computers.
2. XPC target is known but it just make connection between one host PC or hardware and one target PC and the target PC shall have real time OS. so it doesn't cover this problem.
3. There is a library for Matlab titled "Hardware Input / Output Library for Matlab / Simulink " by Werner.Zimmermann that have some good facilities such that it can make simulink to be run near real- time and it can make connection and send data via TCP/IP between two computers but it seems it can just make the connection between two computers running simulink.

It also have some constraints for OS and version of Matlab/Simulink and is not updated. So I'm not sure it would be enough.

After all of these, does anyone know a better way of handling this problem? I would appreciate any help on any of these topics to be useful or another ways to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to run a Simulink model in this distributed manner? It complicates a possilbe solution tremendiously, and to the best of my knowledge it will not be possible without a serious development effort!

Answer (score 0):

see the following links (especially the first one):

- http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/instrument/brbv41k-1.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4934
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27290